# why the act did not output anything when run GitHub actions in local

Tags: github-actions, act

When I am using this command to run [act](https://github.com/nektos/act) in local macOS 13.2 with M1 chip:

```
act -j deploy --bind . --secret-file .env --container-architecture linux/amd64
```

the command did not have anything output. why did this happen? I did not know the process running status. this is the `~/.actrc` config:

```
-P ubuntu-latest=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest
-P ubuntu-22.04=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-22.04
-P ubuntu-20.04=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-20.04
-P ubuntu-18.04=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-18.04
```

this is the act version:

```
> act --version
act version 0.2.46
```